# Bicycles.SE.com Error within an error

Tags: support, status-completed

What's going on with Bicycles.stackexchange.com.  It's returning an error, and there's an error processing the error page.  When going there, I get this message.

> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An exception occurred while processing your request.
>   Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom
>   error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Comment: This may be correlated to **`Stack Overflow will be read-only briefly around 5PM UTC while we move some servers to a different rack. We really hope this works.`**

Comment: Someone pulled the wrong cable :)

Comment: Odd that all the other sites I frequent seem to be up. I don't think that bicycles would warrant it's own server.

Comment: Super User just went into *"This site is currently in read-only mode; we’ll return with full functionality soon."*, so I guess @Frédéric is right (albeit 35 minutes early).

Comment: It works again since a few seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us know if you are still seeing an error - we are currently moving databases around.

Comment: Looks like it's back up and running.

Comment: So you think you can get away with not explaining the *"We really hope this works"*? :-)

Comment: @Geoff still seeing those errors on [su]

Comment: @Sathya: SU's back for me (got a funky re-login sequence though, but all good now)

Comment: @Sathya, SU is fine for me too, and clicking "log in" nicely triggered the network wide auto-login.

Comment: yes it's operational now