# Citizen Patrol badge broken again

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, flags, badges

My [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563422/danny-beckett) shows 'helpful flags: 2' and yet and I haven't got the [Citizen Patrol badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/8/citizen-patrol). The accepted answer on [a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6120/citizen-patrol-badge-not-awarded) of this question shows that it's been broken on and off.

So is it broken again or is it only for certain posts?

Comment: How long ago where the flags marked as helpful? It can take a while to award badges.

Comment: The badge is given when you flag the first post, independently from the fact it was considered helpful, or not. There are a cron tasks that are executed to assign badges. For what I understood, they don't run all at the same time: Some tasks run more frequently, and some tasks run at a specific moment of the day. That could explain why some badges are not immediately awarded.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I flagged my first post maybe a week ago. Then I figured it was maybe only when they were helpful. The last 2 I flagged yesterday (same 2 that were helpful).

Comment: @MartijnPieters because I apparently can't tag more than 1 person in a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So is it broken again or is it only for certain posts?

Despite the fact that the Citizen Patrol badge got awarded multiple times in the last couple of hours, there's a good chance that this is related to the fact that Stack Overflow is currently moving its databases. ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147218))

However, if you only flagged two comments so far, it would also explain why you didn't get a badge.

The description for the badge simply says:

> First flagged post.

In this context, *post* means question or answer, but **not** comment. ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5326))